# Parsing data in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am wanting to parse some information from a JSON file. I cant find a find to successfully retrieve the data I want.

In a file I want to output the profile name.

This is the code on how I am reading and parsing.

```
with open(json_data) as f:
        accounts = dict(json.loads(f.read()))
        shell_script = accounts['OCredit']['Profile Name']
        print(shell_script)
```

This gives me the output of

```
OCredit
```

In a sense this is what I want, but in the application the value thats now "OCredit"(first bracket) would depend on the user.

```
with open(json_data) as f:
        accounts = dict(json.loads(f.read()))
        shell_script = accounts['OCredit']
        print(shell_script)
```

This outputs :

```
{'Profile Name': 'OCredit', 'Name': 'Andrew Long', 'Email': 
'asasa@yahoo.com', 'Tel': '2134568790', 'Address': '213 clover ','Zip': 
'95305', 'City': 'brooklyn', 'State': 'NY','CreditCard':'213456759090', 
'EXP': '12/21', 'CVV': '213'}
```

The actual JSON file is :

```
{'OCredit': {'Profile Name': 'OCredit',
 'Name': 'Andrew Long',
 'Email': 'asasa@yahoo.com',
 'Tel': '2134568790',
 'Address': '213 clover ',
 'Zip': '95305',
 'City': 'Brooklyn',
 'State': 'NY',
 'CreditCard': '213456759090',
 'EXP': '12/21',
 'CVV': '213'}}
```

So, to sum it up. I want to get inside JSON file and just print out the value that "Profile Name" has without hardcoding the fist value of the bracket.

Im not sure if I have to change the way im saving the JSON file to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for key in accounts:
    print(accounts[key]['Profile Name'])
    # OCredit
```

Or:

```
for value in accounts.values():
    print(value['Profile Name'])
```

Comment: @BigO the second one also works on your given example, maybe there's something more in your usecase?